# i have an error of a.any() and a.all() value error in the if statement

Tags: python, numpy

i am getting an error File

```
"C:/Users/user/tensorEnv/project.py", line 28, in <module>
    if N <= 100 :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

can someone tell me how to use `a.any()` or `a.all()` or help me fix this issue

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
r3=np.arange(1.11,10,0.1)
r1=1
r2=1.1
k=5
R1cond=3.36*10**(-3)
R2cond=(1/k)*(0.0727-(0.08/r3))
Rconv=(0.004)/(r3**2)
Rtotal=Rconv+R1cond+R2cond
qloss=975/Rtotal
t=176
Q=qloss*t
L0=[]
L0.append(Q)
L0=[x*10**(-3) for x in L0]
#E is the price of EDL in LBP/NW.h
#Eel is the electric price to pay
#t is the time of working hours of the furnace 22 business days
#E=Eel*qloss*t
L=[]
L1=[]
L2=[]
L3=[]
L4=[]
for N in L0:
        if N <= 100 :
                L.append(35*N)
        if N <= 300 and N > 100:
                L1.append( 55*N)
        if N <=400 and N > 300:
                L2.append(80*N)
        if N <= 500 and N > 400:
                L3.append(120*N)
        if N > 500 :
                L4.append(200*N)
plt.plot(L)
plt.plot(L1)
plt.plot(L2)
plt.plot(L3)
plt.plot(L4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you expect `N` to be?  As written `L0` is a list of numpy arrays.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code is written, the variable `N` stores each item of `L0` for every iteration. It looks like `L0` is a list containing `Q` based on the code preceding the loop. This is due to the `r3 = np.arange()` line.

One of the first things I would do is confirm that things are working as expected. For example, adding a simple `print(N)` inside the loop to confirm that `N` truly is an array of floating values (i.e. `Q`):

```
for N in L0:
    print( N )
    ...
```

Assuming all this is expected, it is not syntactically correct to compare an array to a single value, which is why the error suggested using either the `.all()` or `.any()` functions. This would have a syntax like the following if we are checking if **any** of the elements in `N` (and therefore `Q`) is greater than or equal to 100:

```
if ( N <= 100 ).any():
    ...
```

And the following if we want to check if **all** the elements in `N` is greater than or equal to 100:

```
if ( N <= 100 ).all():
    ...
```

Comment: it worked thank you but my plot of L,L1,L2,L3,L4 is giving an empty figure why

Comment: If you examine the `L`, `L1`, etc variables after the `for` loop (e.g. `print( L )`, you will see that your variable is a list containing an array (i.e. `[array([...])]`). To plot the data, you just want to feed in the array, so you would plot it via `plot( L[0] )`, which calls the first array of the `L` list of arrays. Also, when you examine your variables, you will notice that all your numbers are in the 1e5 range, so most of your if/else statements are useless...